# What is the difference between SCLK and CLK pins?

Tags: adafruit, teensy, pcb-design

Please do forgive me if anything in this question does not make sense, I am very new to PCB and Arduino.

I am following a tutorial through where the person doing it is making a small data computer (for a balloon or drone, I don't know) on Eagle By Autodesk. I am on a part of the tutorial where an SD & MMC card reader is being used. The instuctor is using a library he has made himself, whilst I am using the default Adafruit library. On his library for the SD card reader, he has a CLK pin, however on the default Adafruit library there is the SCLK pin.

Is there a difference between SCLK pins and CLK pins? And am I ok just to use the CLK pin?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Which Arduino board are you using?

Comment: @sempaiscuba The Teensy 3.2 (it's not technically an Arduino).

Comment: Ah.  Just that you tagged your question as *arduino-uno*, which doesn't have either an SCLK or a CLK pin.

Comment: @sempaiscuba yeah sorry, my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"CLK" stands for "CLocK". "S" stands for "Serial". So "SCLK" is "Serial CLocK". You also get "SCL" (often used for I2C) and "SCK" meaning the same thing.

An SD card has multiple modes of communication: serial, or 4-bit parallel (called SDIO). A clock is a clock whether it is used for serial or parallel communication. What you call it doesn't really matter, at best it just gives a hint about what kind of communication it is used for.

It's like some people use MOSI/MISO and some use SDO/SDI, or DO/DI. There's no standard. It's just data moving one way, data moving the other, and some form of clock to keep it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Well they both are clock pin, but on an arduino uno the sclk pin may refer to the spi clock pin while the clk may refer to the i2c clock pin. I2C and SPI are two communication protocols. So if you know which one you're using take action with the corresponding pins.

I Think the best would be for you to share the tutorial you are following and the place in the code you dont underst

Comment: Though with I2C the clock pin is commonly called SCL. So again another version of these similar abbreviations.